# Use custom function as a view function in Class Based Views in django

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I have a class-based view like this:

```
class MyView(View):

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(MyView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, request):
        return HttpResponse('Get method')
```

And in urls.py I refer to this view like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', MyView.as_view(), name='index'),
]
```

Now, I want to create a custom view function within MyView and use it in urlpatterns.  Something like this:

```
class MyView(View):

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(MyView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, request):
        return redirect(reverse('auth:index'))

    def custom(self, request):
        return HttpResponse('Custom')
```

And in urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', MyView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^/custom/$', MyView.custom(), name='custom'),
]
```

Is it possible to do?

Comment: you don't need to define a new url for your custom function. Just use the function from anywhere in the class using self.custom.

Comment: @MuhammadShoaib but what if I intentionally want to define a new url for that function?

Comment: so you will have to create a new classBaseView.  You cannot add url to the existing view

Comment: Well, what happens when you try to do it? You haven't said whether or not you've tried it, and what happens.